# Correct way to pass Eigen's Ref objects to its Map class to avoid conversion error

Tags: c++, memory-management, pass-by-reference, eigen

I wish to pass an object created by the Ref class as an argument to the Map class to change a vector into a matrix without affecting its contents.
For example, I have the function declaration:

```
double obj_fun(const Ref<const VectorXd>& params){
Map<MatrixXd> D(params.data(), 3, 2);
return 0.0;}
```

I have seen related questions such as [Correct Usage of Eigen class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21132538/correct-usage-of-the-eigenref-class) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40296924/eigenref-as-a-member-variable) but neither address how the Map class interacts with objects created by the Ref class. From the first question's answer, I can surmise that method six is amenable to changing a matrix's orientation but not its content, which would be akin to a declaration like

```
double obj_fun(Ref<VectorXd>&){(…)}
```

but that did not work.

Using the declaration in the conventional way as [recommended by Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html)  which I did in my code above or 'type 1' in the first linked question, produces the error "cannot convert argument 1 from 'const double *' to 'double *'" and a similar error ensues if I use the latter method (method 6 in the other question).

The only way in which to make it work is to do

```
double obj_fun(VectorXd& params) {(…)}
```

which seems silly as it goes against convention to declare memory addresses as constants. Hence, the only way out now seems to be to pass a physical copy to my function, which I'd like to avoid. However, I assume this is safer as otherwise I am leaving a memory address liable to be manipulated.

Comment: If you don't want to change `D`, use `Map<const MatrixXd> D(params.data(), 3, 2);` If you need to change it, you must pass `Ref<const VectorXd> params` (without `&`) to `obj_fun`

Comment: Thank you so much @chtz that solved it completely, in both cases. If you put that into an answer I shall accept it as 'the' answer!