# Having Ref object as class member

Tags: c++, memory-management, reference, eigen

I wish to pass by reference my data to a class where the reference itself should be the public variable, to be accessed by member functions. If I declare my class and its constructor

```
class max_likelihood { 
public: 
MatrixXd dat
max_likelihood(const Ref<const MatrixXd>& dat_in)
{dat = dat_in;}
```

I get functioning code but end up creating a copy of `dat`, which I would like to avoid.

I have tried to do instead:

```
class max_likelihood {
public:
const Ref<const MatrixXd>& dat;
max_likelihood(const Ref<const MatrixXd>& dat){}
```

But this does not work and/or won't let me access the reference to `dat` and does not even compile.

Based on my research I have found this bit from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40296924/eigenref-as-a-member-variable)

> if you want to reassign a Ref to reference another buffer, then use a placement new to re-call the constructor of Ref. Don't forget to call the destructor first.

I believe this may help answer my question but I do not know what these instructions would mean in practice, hence my question here. Specifically, I suppose I am creating a new instance of a Ref object to pass around the passed reference. How can I interpret the answer to this or find a more elegant way to use `Ref` objects within classes when the source data is created elsewhere, say read in from a file via main?

Comment: Have you considered changing `max_likelihood` to take your argument by value or adding an overload that takes it's argument by rvalue reference? You could avoid the copy in cases where it isn't needed.

Comment: Using placement new won't save you a copy. The linked question is a move in the wrong direction.

Comment: Please share a [MCVE] to better illustrate the use case.

Comment: Do not overcomplicate the matter, use move semantics

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Ref is a class given by a library Eigen https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get functioning code but end up creating a copy of dat, which I would like to avoid.

Using reference to avoid data copy in this case is a terrible idea, maintaining reference in a class makes things quite complicated. So if `MatrixXd` properly designed for C++11 or later just use move semantics:

```
class max_likelihood { 
public: 
   MatrixXd dat;
   max_likelihood(MatrixXd dat_in) : dat( std::move(dat_in) ) {}
   ...
};
```

if not dynamically allocate it and transfer ownership:

```
class max_likelihood {  
public: 
   std::unique_ptr<MatrixXd> dat;
   max_likelihood(std::unique_ptr<MatrixXd> dat_in) : dat( std::move(dat_in) ) {}
   ...
};
```

Usually having reference in a class is not a good idea, first of all you need to be careful for not getting dangling reference, second - you will have complications if you decide to allow your object to be copied and/or assigned.

Comment: reading a bit about the problem I think this is a very good solution. If I were to have more arguments in addition to dat, would the syntax for that be like that of inheritance, i.e. separated by commas?

Comment: This answer is pretty silly, as the exact same thing can be accomplished without using move semantics and instead storing a reference to a MatrixXd& as a member (and avoid the copy just the same, and no issues with dangling references if using RAII correctly for the MatrixXd object.) The real reason to use Eigen::Ref is to allow your code to take general Eigen types as inputs (see Eigen doc for details.)

Answer (score 1):

The member variable `dat` is a const reference that needs to be initialized.

```
max_likelihood(const Ref<const MatrixXd>& argdat):dat(argdat){}
```

You may want to use a non const ref instead:

```
class max_likelihood {
public:
Ref<const MatrixXd> dat;
max_likelihood(const Ref<const MatrixXd>& dat):dat(argdat){}
```

At least you get a local ref.

Comment: This solution is way too dangerous and I do not think OP understand all implications.

Comment: Removed the const Ref&, I agree that it is not useful, will be slower and may crash.

Comment: @Slava very likely yes, So I was just about to write an example but thought my q is sufficiently trivial that it can be solved on the spot. I have tried to pre-declare dat as either a MatrixXd in my header (resulting in a copy) or as a reference. Is that what you meant and what this solution does? Or the comment is right. :-)

Comment: @Hirek getting const reference and keeping it is error prone solution - for example you can easily pass temporary and get dangling reference. In general - having reference (const or not) in a class is not a good idea.

Comment: @Slava ok so you are actually saying that it is better in this case to pass by value, i.e. hand the physical data over to the class (and then pass around by reference internally I suppose) just in terms of style?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. Slava's solution moves the data around. If you just need to reference data that is available and stored someplace else, then you should do what I used.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I do not think OP needs reference itslef quote "I get functioning code but end up creating a copy of dat, which I would like to avoid."

Comment: Doesn't mean that the moved matrix is not used later in the process.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher yes, I wish to pass by reference to avoid having to copy relatively large data sets, the reference itself directly is not used. I just need to access the data (by memory location) and the data do not change.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher hmm, so I take some of its columns, copy those into new objects etc. but they will not change themselves

Comment: I would then use Ref, yes, like what I did, and then I would use views ont he Eigen matrices to do my computations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the initializer list:

```
struct max_likelihood { 
    MatrixXd& dat
    max_likelihood(MatrixXd& dat_in) : dat(dat_in) {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set and access a reference like this:

```
class max_likelihood {
public:
   max_likelihood( const MatrixXd& input_dat): dat(input_dat) { }
   const MatrixXd& dat;
};
```

But you cannot change the reference, i.e. re-assign it to another object to reference.

If you need this functionality, then you have to change the member variable to be a pointer, then you can easily change the pointer. And if you don't want the users of your class having to use a pointer, you could add a method that returns a reference.

If you implement the pointer solution, keep in mind that the original object has to persist as long as anypody tries to access it using you `max_likelihood` class. Maybe you should use a `std::shared_ptr<>` to prevent memory leaks.